# SharePoint 2013 - Add all current and future users to a blog

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, blogs

What is the easiest way to add all current SharePoint users as followers on a blog?  Also need to have something setup where any future users are also automatically added to this blog.

Bonus.... If they would automatically be signed up for email alerts when something is added to the blog that would be great too!

Comment: you can add the Everyone group and give contribute access, but i dont recommend the e-mail alerts to everyone, they will hate you for that.

Answer (score 0):

We can add all users as followers on a blog using [SPSocialFollowingManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFollowingManager.aspx) class.

For future, we can create a new security event receiver on your web site, to handle group user added and group users deleted event.

The following articles for your reference:

[Programmatically Follow Documents in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/31/programmatically-follow-documents-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[How to add programmatically users as followers with new SPSecurityEventReceiver in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ocarpen/2012/08/03/how-to-add-programmatically-users-as-followers-with-new-spsecurityeventreceiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)